# SSRS export save without asking file name

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services

I have this SSRS report someone wrote that spits out a table of data and you can export to file.  I would like to have it save automatically in my downloads folder without asking for file name.  For all the file format except for .pdf it doesn't ask for file name and just save it in the download folder but for .pdf it would open this window.  What is causing this for only the .pdf format?

I checked the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" and it's unchecked in Chrome not sure what else may be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't belong here and should be moved to [super user](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the file automatically without asking for the file name is a browser setting and unrelated to SSRS.